# Does an invoice needs a front paper?

Tags: print-design, interaction

<sup>*A little bit in followup with [my previous topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51802/how-would-you-create-an-experience-with-an-invoice-keeping-ink-cartridges-in-m), with a few discussions additionally.*</sup>

I'm stuck with something, which might be either personal or actually based on facts, but.. The thing is: Does an invoice needs a front paper?

Or other ways to describe the question: Is it bad to have (not)?

---

**A few arguments in favor**

- A build up. Not the costs directly in the face
- Can have a nice, peaceful design
- Create an 'experience', in favor of the negative one: The costs

**A few arguments against**

- An additional page that the client needs to click, scroll, swipe *("interaction design")*
- Not directly the content they request (costs)
- Another sheet of paper, additional ink

Comment: The cost of your services should not be a negative, the customer should feel that they are getting good value for the money -- making an invoice less convenient (and use twice as much paper when printed) is not going to make anyone feel that they are getting good value. If you're submitting a proposal, then sure, add a cover page and some page(s) of explanation of why your service is worth it, but by the time you send an invoice, you already won their business, don't make it less convenient for them to pay you.

Comment: I have to disagree with all arguments in favor: there is no build up. A price is agreed upon long before that. Not sure what a peaceful design is, not sure why you need peace. And Johnny already said everything about the 'experience'.

Comment: And, it's not just an additional piece of paper that the client needs to click, scroll, swipe (nothing to do with "interaction design"), print and understand, most of all. Nobody has time to bother with, what they will perceive, unnecessary pages.

Comment: Great arguments, ones that have crossed my mind. And I feel that, they fit quite the answer to this 'question'. Thank you very much

Comment: I have to also disagree with anything you have listed as a "pro" to a two page invoice.  I don't know why you would want a build-up or an experience.  If I go to a restaurant, I don't want a book with the last page telling me what I owe, I just want to know how much to pay so I can get on with my day.  The invoice should be concise and to the point, in my opinion.  Just get the info to them in a timely and orderly manner, so they can [hopefully] do the same with your money.

Comment: An invoice is a cut-and-dried business communication document. You're in the business of visual communication so I'd suggest you keep it straightforward, simple, and very much too-the-point: here's the services rendered, here's what you owe me.

Comment: ----- shouldn't *all* the above comments be answers?

Comment: They should, hehe :)