# What typeface to use based on personality traits?

Tags: texture, typefaces

I want to make my own online resumé website, so that I could show it to future employers. I'm currently working on choosing typefaces based on personal traits I want to portray which are: dynamic,professional,trustable and innovative. 
I also would like to know which typeface characteristics should I look into to achieve the aforementioned traits. I know that for example to portray a friendly and warm feeling I should look for rounded typefaces with open counters,but except that I don't know much more about looking into characteristics to get to the results I look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who looks at a lot of résumés, may I say... please don't do this. Just make it clean and readable. Really. Dazzle me with your portfolio. But your CV needs to be something I can read *fast*. I'm looking for specific keywords based on the job I'm filling, how long you've been working, and the software you know.

This question/answer is not quite a duplicate but it's closely related:
[Is a graphical/original resume a good idea for a designer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5906/is-a-graphical-original-resume-a-good-idea-for-a-designer/5908#5908)

If I can't find the keywords I need in one, possibly two quick reads, I'm going to move on to the next résumé from the inch-thick stack in front of me.

Comment: Indeed I want to make a resume which has a clean and readable body text,but since the website which will accomodate my resumé probably will have some sort of heading as introduction I wanted it to give a certaint style, so I was looking for what characteristics to look into to achieve the look I want.

Comment: @CarlaRaquel I understand. My point is that "the look you want" sounds to me like it will be counterproductive to the goals of "clean and readable" and "getting you hired." I am pretty good at identifying basic (not esoteric) typefaces on sight, and after more than 10 years of reading résumés, I could not tell you the "special" font of one single CV I've ever seen, nor has font choice influenced my decision beyond "readable/unreadable." You are trying to solve a problem which a hiring manager doesn't have.